# Error al abrir un APK en otros dispositivos Android

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Construyo mi APK sin ningún problema ya sea la debug o la release, las dos se construyen sin problema aparente. 
Cabe destacar que yo genero la APK en Build>Generate Signed APK.
hasta alli todo bien, transfiero la aplicacion a mi dispositivo por medio de USB y la instalo manualmente (con origenes desconocidos). Me funciona perfecto!!!

El problema es que si se la paso a alguien mas no les funciona, es decir, la aplicacion se detiene al intentar abrirla (si se instala).

**Detalles de la aplicacion**

Estoy utilizando la API de Google Maps, mas sin embargo no me consta que el SHA1 que genero (La genero con `keytool -list -v -keystore keyAndroid.jks`)sea el apropiado, debido a que cuando lo filtro por medio del paquete y de su SHA1 en:

https://console.developers.google.com/

al momento de abrir mi app en **mi dispositivo** no me muestra el mapa. Entonces para que me lo muestre no le pongo el paquete ni la clave SHA1 (La dejo sin restricciones).

Siguiendo con la logica anterior, de no agregar la clave SHA1 ni el paquete a la APi de Google Maps, esto debido a que asi si me muestra el mapa y funciona perfectamente bien en mi dispositivo (al instalarla por origenes desconocidos).
Entonces asi mismo quiero probar la aplicacion en otro dispositivo distinto, pero en este no abre la aplicacion (si se instala).

PD:
Estoy trabajando sobre la API 15 (Android 4.0.3)
El error que muestra es "Se ha detenido la aplicacion".

Comment: Al principio estás mencionando que el error sucede al instalar, y luego que sucede al abrir. Entiendo que son casos diferentes. Para cada uno de esos casos, podrías [edit] la pregunta agregando la versión de Android e incluir el error que se genera al instalar o al abrir, según sea el caso?

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta, espero y quede mas claro :)

Comment: Lamentablemente, _Se ha detenido la aplicación_  no nos proporciona ningún tipo de información. Lo que tienes que hacer es ver el logcat del error y ahi si tienes información que te puede ayudar a saber cual es tu problema.

Comment: Mira el logcat, y mira que tengas los permisos necesarios tanto agregados en el manifest, como en la configuración de tu teléfono

Comment: En mi experiencia creo que el problema no esta claro, pero es principalmente porque el error se genera en otros dispositivos diferentes al que usas para prueba. Trata o intenta crear un emulador con características similares a los teléfonos que dan el problema y siempre revisa el Logcat. Ciertamente como ya varios compañeros en la comunidad lo han mencionado el problema puede generarse por muchas razones por lo que intenta probar con diferentes configuraciones del emulador tratando de replicar el problema. Espero que mi comentario sea de ayuda.

Comment: Un punto importante es saber es que OS tiene el dispositivo donde la instalas y funciona,  y que OS tiene el dispositivo donde no funciona, te aconsejo agregar tu build.gradle. En cuanto al mensaje "Se ha detenido la aplicacion", en este punto debes revisar en el LogCat ahí se mostrarán más detalles acerca de este problema. En cuanto que no te muestré el mapa es un problema diferente que considero debes separar en tu pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahorita probare ese consejo del Logcat.Les cuento que paso despues :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya funciono. El error fue por que le habia asignado transparencia a una barra del Layout, entonces en algunas versiones de android no funcionaba.

Para solucionarlo simplemente cambie el color y listo.

PD:
El error lo descubri con el Logcat, Gracias!! :D